# How to send image in a sd card through bluetooth

Tags: android

I have stored an image in a gallery path. I just want to know how to send that image path only through bluetooth instead of sending through ACTION_SEND Command. Please Help me with the clear answer to restrict the datas to send only through bluetooth

Comment: What have you done so far? The Android API guide has an excellent Bluetooth demonstration that you can find here. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use package com.android.bluetooth in order to pass the intents only through bluetooth...

Answer (score 1):

BluetoothTexting.java

```
public class BluetoothTexting extends Activity {

private static int DISCOVERY_REQUEST = 1;

private Handler handler = new Handler();
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> foundDevices;
private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> aa; 
private ListView list;

private BluetoothAdapter bluetooth;
private BluetoothSocket socket;
private UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

configureBluetooth();
setupListView();    
setupSearchButton();
setupListenButton();
}

private void configureBluetooth() {
bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}

private void setupListenButton() {
Button listenButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_listen);
listenButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent disc = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    startActivityForResult(disc, DISCOVERY_REQUEST);     
  }
});
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == DISCOVERY_REQUEST) {
  boolean isDiscoverable = resultCode > 0;
  if (isDiscoverable) {
    String name = "bluetoothserver";
    try {
      final BluetoothServerSocket btserver = 
        bluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, uuid);

      AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket> acceptThread = 
        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket>() {

        @Override
        protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(Integer... params) {
          try {
            socket = btserver.accept(params[0]*1000);
            return socket;
          } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());            
          }
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(BluetoothSocket result) {
          if (result != null)
            switchUI();
        }            
      };          
      acceptThread.execute(resultCode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());            
    }
  }
}
}

private void setupListView() {
aa = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this, 
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
           foundDevices);
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_discovered);    
list.setAdapter(aa);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, 
                          int index, long arg3) {
    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> connectTask = 
      new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() { 
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
          try {
            BluetoothDevice device = foundDevices.get(params[0]);
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            socket.connect();              
          } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH_CLIENT", e.getMessage());
          }
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          switchUI();
        }
      };
    connectTask.execute(index);
  }      
});
}

private void setupSearchButton() {
 Button searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_search);

 searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    registerReceiver(discoveryResult, 
                     new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

    if (!bluetooth.isDiscovering()) {
      foundDevices.clear();
      bluetooth.startDiscovery();
    }
  }
});
}

private void switchUI() {    
 final TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_messages);
 final EditText textEntry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_message);

 messageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 textEntry.setEnabled(true);

 textEntry.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
  public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) {
      sendMessage(socket, textEntry.getText().toString());
      textEntry.setText("");
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }      
});
BluetoothSocketListener bsl = new BluetoothSocketListener(socket, handler, messageText);
Thread messageListener = new Thread(bsl);
messageListener.start();
}

private void sendMessage(BluetoothSocket socket, String msg) {
 OutputStream outStream;
 try {
  outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
  byte[] byteString = (msg + " ").getBytes();
  byteString[byteString.length - 1] = 0;
  outStream.write(byteString);
} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
}    
}

BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;
  remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
  if (bluetooth.getBondedDevices().contains(remoteDevice)) {  
    foundDevices.add(remoteDevice);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
};

private class MessagePoster implements Runnable {
private TextView textView;
private String message;

public MessagePoster(TextView textView, String message) {
  this.textView = textView;
  this.message = message;
}

public void run() {
  textView.setText(message);
}     
 }

 private class BluetoothSocketListener implements Runnable {

  private BluetoothSocket socket;
  private TextView textView;
  private Handler handler;

  public BluetoothSocketListener(BluetoothSocket socket, 
                                 Handler handler, TextView textView) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.textView = textView;
    this.handler = handler;
  }

public void run() {
  int bufferSize = 1024;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];      
  try {
    InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();
    int bytesRead = -1;
    String message = "";
    while (true) {
      message = "";
      bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
      if (bytesRead != -1) {
        while ((bytesRead==bufferSize)&&(buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)) {
          message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
          bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
        }
        message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1); 

        handler.post(new MessagePoster(textView, message));              
        socket.getInputStream();
      }
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
  } 
 }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please post the xml layout. I am new to android so for me it is bit tough to understand the coding